# ElasticSearch SearchContextMissingException - No search context found for id

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using ES version 1.6.0 and the Python plugin for ES. I have a large collection of documents inside my index and I want to iterate through each and every document inside the index. In this sense I am using scan to get each document and retrieve the sentences it contains. I have written my function using an iterator to yield back each and every sentence. My code is this:

```
es1 = Elasticsearch(["http://localhost:9200"], timeout=30)

class Sentences(object):

def __init__(self, index, query):

    self.index = index

    self.query = query

def __iter__(self):

    for doc in scan(es1, query=self.query, index=self.index):

        doc_sentences = doc["_source"]["doc_sentences"]

        for sentence in doc_sentences:

            yield sentence
```

The iterator appers to be running initially, but after a while I get the error: "SearchContextMissingException - No search context found for id" followed by a list of document ids. I tried to increase the ES timeout, but didn't help. What can I do to overcome this?

Comment: Is this scan&scroll? If so, you need a `scroll` value specified, to keep the search context open long enough.

Comment: Hi @AndreiStefan, thx for your reply. You mean I should use scroll instead of scan to keep the search context open? Weird enough, the same code works if I don't yield anything. Will try with scroll now.